# How can I detect the amount a value has changed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a 2D game in unity using C#, I want the "time" to increase based on the amount of change occurring in the x and y values of the gameobject, for example if the gameobject starts at 1 position y and falls until 0.2 position y the score would add 0.8, except I want it to be an integer so something more like 10.

I tried to do some code but it doesn't really work as it just adds the position of x and y until unity crashes, can someone please help me with this? Thanks!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ScoreEasy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float time = 1;
    public float posX;
    public float posY;
    public Text score;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;

    public void Start()
    {

    }
    public void Update()
    {
        posX = gameObject.transform.position.x;
        posY = gameObject.transform.position.y;

        time = posX + posY;

        score.text = time.ToString("0");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to want to cache the position of the object from the last frame to determine the change of position. As well, it seems you want the overall displacement from the last frame, not the distance as distance is both a direction and scalar. Meaning it can be negative, which would decrease your score.

The reason Unity crashes with your program is most likely an overflow. You are continually adding the position of your object together and adding that to a variable every frame.

You can do something like:

```
public class ScoreEasy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float time = 1;
    public Text score;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;

    private float lastXPos;
    private float lastYPos;
    
    private void Start()
    {
        lastXPos = transform.position.x;
        lastYPos = transform.position.y;
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        // increase our time by a factor of the movement we had since last frame
        time += 10f * (Mathf.Abs(lastXPos - transform.position.x) + Mathf.Abs(lastYPos - transform.position.y));
        
        // store our current frame as our last for the next frame
        lastXPos = transform.position.x;
        lastYPos = transform.position.y;
        
        // visually update the value
        score.text = time.ToString("0");
    }
}
```

Instead of adding the positions together, I am adding the absolute difference of the position from the last frame. As you also mentioned wanting the score to be larger, you can just multiply the value by 10 or some other scalar.

Edit: Here is a gif of the above example. The score can get rather high, so you can reduce the scalar of 10 to any factor you desire.

[image: Example]

Edit 2: To have the speed of the object factor into the score added, you can simply have the distance moved be scaled by the magnitude of the velocity of the object. If this value appears to be too great, you can divide the magnitude or clamp it so it is not so severe.

```
time += rb.velocity.magnitude * (Mathf.Abs(lastXPos - transform.position.x) + Mathf.Abs(lastYPos - transform.position.y));
```

Edit 3: Here is the updated code working:

[image: Updated code]

Comment: THere's actually an issue, even if the gameobject is barely moving and extremely slow the score still increases at the same rate as if the object were moving very fast, do you know how to fix this?

Comment: You could have the scalar be the magnitude of the velocity of the object instead of just 10. I'll add an updated line under the gif. Edit: Added the new snippet. Is that more what you expected?

Comment: The score now just displays 1 and doesn't go up

Comment: @ZOMBYSPIDER You have a Rigidbody2D, are you using it at all? If you are not using physics to move the object, that would be why it is always 1 as the velocity would always be 0. What is your movement code like? If you have some sort of speed indicator then multiply the value by that instead of the velocity's magnitude.

Comment: I am just using the gravity function on the rigid body, I don't have any movement scripts

Comment: @ZOMBYSPIDER How would the object barely move vs. move quickly then? If it just has gravity being applied does it just fall quickly and you move back and forth? If that's the case, it should still have velocity. I need to know a bit more about how your object moves. But you will want the score to scale off however fast your object is moving.

Comment: well the object falls at a constant pace but I have another object which is able to affect the movement, if I fling the other object into it the first object speeds up, much like it's possible for the first object to get stuck on the second object, practically making it stationary and not moving, even though it is still affected by gravity the second object is not

Comment: Yes I want the score to increase based on the speed, so if the object is pushed very fast against a wall the score will jump to a higher number whereas if the object is slowly falling it will gradually increase.

Comment: Are you sure that using the `rb.velocity.magnitude` always results in 1? I just tried it with an object falling and the score continually increases faster and faster as the velocity increases.

Comment: I am displaying it on the text and it just says 1

Comment: when the game starts it says 40.031513050250..... and then when the object gets reset to it's position it displays 1

Comment: I am not sure what else you are doing to change velocity. I edited the question showing that my code works. As you have not provided any sort of code or relevant details as to how your velocity is being changed outside of gravity, I am not sure how to help. You need to add more detail. What does `object get reset` mean? How is it resetting?

Comment: So the object gets reset to it's original position when it collides with another object, I'll call it the floor, the velocity gets reset as well

Comment: https://prnt.sc/1tejc6z this is an image of my rigid body on the object

Comment: https://prnt.sc/1tejf2z this is an image of the code

Comment: https://prnt.sc/1tejhm2 here is the inspector window for the script

Comment: I see the issue. I assumed this script was on your player, but you have a player reference. Change the `transform.position` to `obj.transform.position`. Change it everywhere in the script. As you want to use the falling object's positions, not the score managers positions. In your original question, you use `gameObject.transform.position`, which means the object the script is on would be the transform you are attempting to get. In this new snippet, that is not the case.

Comment: That worked! Thanks I guess I forgot to add it when I copied and pasted your edit lmao

Comment: @ZOMBYSPIDER All good. Glad it's working. Good luck!